# Are files in UNIX always owned by an owner and a group?

Tags: linux, unix

For example, when I use `ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4 }'` on my file/folder, I see my username appearing twice.

Does that mean that all files are owned by **one** user and **one** group, which that one group is me? But how can the user also be a group? Why does my name appear twice?

Is a file always owned by one group and a user, or is there really only 1 user all along?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: »» how can the user also be a group «« : A user is member of a group ! .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in Unix systems are always owned by 1 user, and 1 group. In this case, the user name happens to match the name given to the group. You can check out the user and group names at `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.